# Why capture this in cpp in lambda and get reference to data member cause segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>



struct Info
{
    std::string a{"abc"};
};


struct Handlers
{
    std::function<const Info&()> get_info;
};

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        handler_ = Handlers{
            .get_info = [this](){return data;}
        };
    };


    Info data;
    Handlers handler_;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::string k = a.handler_.get_info().a;
    std::cout << k;
}
```

The above code segfault on `std::string k = a.handler_.get_info().a;`

with further investigation I found that `std::cout << &a.handler_.get_info();` prints `0`

I use following version of g++

```
g++ (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and I compile the file with following command

```
g++  main.cpp --std=c++2a
```

Comment: only compiles with gcc <= 12, but fixed in 13 https://godbolt.org/z/cGs3MzhY8

Comment: It's basically the same situation as `string foo() { return "abc"; } const string& bar() { return foo(); }`, which doesn't compile, but apparently `std::function` used to be implemented in such a way that the compiler didn't detect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is that the lambda returns by value, whereas you expect to return reference according to `std::function`.
Storing your lambda into the `std::function` makes the `std::function` return a dangling reference.

Change to:

```
[this]() -> Info& {return data;}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/anTjaojnf)

Comment: @Aconcagua I dont understand it completely, but the lambda does return a value and somehow (this is the part I dont understand yet) the `std::function` returns a reference to that temporary. Simpler example: https://godbolt.org/z/55hvre6Ys

Comment: Remove the `const` from signature passed to `std::function` , and a diagnostic error must appear.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Oh, too much focused on the lambda itself, too little on the `std::function` declaration...